# Add multiple subviews to NSWindow in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have a window with an outlet and a custom view (in my `.xib` file) which contains a button and a text field. When a button is pressed in the window I want to add an instance of the custom view into the window.

Currently I have an outlet to the window and the custom view (`configWindow` and `customView`) and this action is called when the button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func addView(sender: NSButton) {
    configWindow.contentView.addSubview(customView)
    // Print the views in the window, see what's been added
    for i in configWindow.contentView.subviews {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

This will only ever add one view to the window.

Is this the right way to go about it, or should I be using a completely different approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the same view twice. It sounds like you are trying to add the **same** instance of `customView` to `configWindow` multiple times, which you can't do. If you think about it, it's fairly obvious why -- how will the superview manage two subviews which are the same? How will it know the difference between the two of them?

You should be adding different **instances** of the `CustomView` class instead:

```
@IBAction func addView(sender: NSButton) {
    let customView = CustomView(frame: <some frame>)

    configWindow.contentView.addSubview(customView)
    // Print the views in the window, see what's been added
    for i in configWindow.contentView.subviews {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

**Edited to add**
I've created an example project that you can download at https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so-27874883/get/master.zip

This basically initialises multiple views out of a nib file and adds them randomly to a view.

The Interesting part is:

```
class CustomView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!

    class func newCustomView() -> CustomView {
        let nibName = "CustomView"

        // Instantiate an object of this class from the nib file and return it.
        // Variables are explicitly unwrapped, since a failure here is a compile time error.
        var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
        let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: nibName, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())!
        nib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)

        var view: CustomView!

        for object: AnyObject in topLevelObjects! {

            if let obj = object as? CustomView {
                view = obj
                break
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Where I create a factory method of the custom class that loads itself from the nib, and then returns the first top level object of the correct class.

Comment: The custom view is just a 'Custom View' from the xib file, it doesn't have any attached custom class to it, so I don't have anything to create a new instance of.

Comment: It does have a class. Views in nib files have an associated class, whether it is a custom class or a plain old NSView. Again, if you think about, how are you creating a view object, in an object oriented system, without it having a class? How are you getting an instance of `customView`?

Comment: The instance is from an IBOutlet. Is there a way to create an NSView with the attributes found in the outlet?

Comment: By hooking up to an IBOutlet, you are using 1 particular instance of that view that is unarchived at runtime. If you want to use multiple instances of that view you need to create a custom class with an initialiser that knows how to unarchive itself from the nib file and use that instead. If you want mulitple objects out of a nib file you shouldn't be using an IBOutlet.

Comment: Alrighty, can you be more awesome and point me to some docs on creating custom views? (I presume I can still make the layout in a nib file?)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html for more.